# Styling QTabWidget

Tags: css, qt, stylesheet, qt4.8, qtabwidget

I have a QTabWidget with a background gradient and two problems.

1. How dow I remove the anoying outline around the active tab (see image)? I tried "outline: none" like with push buttons but it does not seem to have an effect.
2. How do I style disabled tabs? I tried :disabled and :!enabled but both do not work. **// Edit: This works with :disabled but not with all properties. Seems like I tried the only not supported.**

[image: Anoying focus]

The qt documentation was no help. Google either. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the focus rectangle is handled by the `QStyle` (not to be confused with style sheets) that is in use. You can write a `QStyle` subclass and apply that to your to your `QTabWidget`. The subclass should override the `drawControl()` method and do nothing if it is currently drawing the focus rectangle.

The subclass would look something like this:

**NoFocusRectStyle.h**

```
#ifndef NOFOCUSRECTSTYLE_H
#define NOFOCUSRECTSTYLE_H

#include <QWindowsVistaStyle> // or the QStyle subclass of your choice

class NoFocusRectStyle : public QWindowsVistaStyle
{
public:
    NoFocusRectStyle();

protected:
    void drawControl(ControlElement element, const QStyleOption *option, 
        QPainter *painter, const QWidget *widget = 0) const;
};

#endif // NOFOCUSRECTSTYLE_H
```

**NoFocusRectStyle.cpp**

```
#include "NoFocusStyle.h"

NoFocusRectStyle::NoFocusRectStyle()
{
}

void NoFocusRectStyle::drawControl(ControlElement element, 
    const QStyleOption *option, QPainter *painter, 
    const QWidget *widget) const
{
    if(element == CE_FocusFrame)
        return;

    QWindowsVistaStyle::drawControl(element, option, painter, widget);
}
```

Somewhere in your form's intializer/constructor you would apply the custom style subclass to the tab widget:

```
ui->tabWidget->setStyle(new NoFocusRectStyle());
```

This should allow your style sheets to continue to work.

It would be nice if there was an easier way to do this but I couldn't find one :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Is there a way to do this without a reference to a specific style as I use a static build of qt on linux/mac and windows and it gives me a lot of errors?

Comment: Having to specify a specific style subclass is one of the reasons this solution is not optimal. I'm not sure how that relates to any errors you may be getting though. What errors?

Answer (score 2):

This thread is old but maybe this would help people.

If you don't need to use the focus, then you can just set it through your tab widget:

ui->tabWidget->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);

Answer (score 1):

Focus rectangle could be removed by adding snippet below to your style:

```
QWidget {
    outline: 0;
}
```

It is not related directly to style of QTabWidget but works as you expect.